# Debugging minidumps of crashes on a windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am at a complete loss with this. The articles at msdn either seem to be useless or I'm simply missing some major points.

I have an app which I've released on the store, a simple soundboard. Over the past few days I've had a LOT of crash reports come through which I'd of course like to fix if possible.

I've downloaded the xslx spreadsheet and one of the cab files located in it. I open it in visual studio and get as far as the first picture on: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2014/09/01/debugging-crashes-of-your-apps-and-games-on-windows-phone-8.aspx

The symbols seem to be where im running to problems I guess. The instructions seem about as clear as mud.

I follow the link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557573(v=vs.85).aspx to download sybols. It states: "Run the provided symbols installers from the WDK download on the Windows Connect site"the page doesnt mention anything about symbols. I've read a ton of articles and none really explain any way of doing thing.

I've tried playing around and see if I can figure it out but all I ever seem to get is KERNALBASE.dll not found and no matching binary found.

If anyone can point me in the right direction on how to get anywhere at all with this I'd be greatly appreciative.

the app was written in visual studio express 2012 in C#

Comment: the symbols are online. Add this to the symbol settings: srv*c:\symbols\WP*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;

Comment: More details, please; where should one add this? Is c:\symbols\WP a local path?